# Cordova accelerometer extern

Tags: google-closure-compiler, google-closure

I'm writing a wrapper for Cordova's core plugins and lifecycle events. The code is fine but I've been having trouble getting the externs to work properly.

As an example, here is an extern I've tried for the [accelerometer plugin](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.device-motion) which has three methods and an `acceleration` object.

```
/**
 * @fileoverview Externs for Cordova's accelerometer plugin
 *
 * @externs
 */

/**
 * @type {Object}
 * @const
 */
var navigator.accelerometer;

/**
 * @typedef {{x: number, y: number, z: number, timestamp: number}}
 */
navigator.accelerometer.Acceleration;

/**
 * @param {function(navigator.accelerometer.Acceleration)} success
 * @param {Function} err
 */
navigator.accelerometer.prototype.getCurrentAcceleration = function(success, err) {};

/**
 * @param {function(navigator.accelerometer.Acceleration)} success
 * @param {Function} err
 * @param {Object=} period
 * @return {string}
 */
navigator.accelerometer.prototype.watchAcceleration = function(success, err, period) {};

/**
 * @param {string} watch
 */
navigator.accelerometer.prototype.clearWatch  = function(watch) {};
```

If I use this for `navigator.accelerometer.getCurrentAcceleration`, the code is munged to `navigator.b.c`. Any ideas for what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this was a dumb question because the problem was with my setup not the extern file. I'm not very good at writing extern files but here's a slightly better version of the same extern (let me know if this can be improved):

```
/**
* @fileoverview Externs for Cordova's accelerometer plugin
*
* @externs
*/

/**
 * @type {Object}
 * @const
 */
navigator.accelerometer = {};

/**
 * @typedef {{x: number, y: number, z: number, timestamp: number}}
 */
navigator.accelerometer.Acceleration;

/**
 * @param {function(navigator.accelerometer.Acceleration)} success
 * @param {Function} err
 */
navigator.accelerometer.getCurrentAcceleration = function(success, err) {};

/**
 * @param {function(navigator.accelerometer.Acceleration)} success
 * @param {Function} err
 * @param {Object=} period
 * @return {string}
 */
navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration = function(success, err, period) {};

/**
 * @param {string} watch
 */
navigator.accelerometer.clearWatch  = function(watch) {};
```

EDIT: [Here's a collection](https://github.com/greenyouse/browserific/tree/master/browserific/src/browserific/cordova/externs) of Cordova plugin externs in case anyone's interested.